# run Terminal script that executes one command and while that command is running, opens a new tab and runs another command

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

At the moment I am making a java application. To test it I have to run a server and then a client.

So I want to run this using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
gradle runServer
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
gradle runClient
```

**Problem**: The server when run **does not end** until you close the game, so the next two commands **will not execute**. How can I run them **concurrently/simultaneously** ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the server in the background, then kill it when the script is done.

Here’s an example with a simple HTTP server and client.

```
#!/bin/bash

date > foo.txt
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1234 &
SERVER_PID="${!}"
# Automatically terminate server on script exit
trap 'kill "${SERVER_PID}"' 0 1 2 3 15

# Wait for server to start
while ! netstat -an -f inet | grep -q '\.1234 '; do
    sleep 0.05
done

# Run client
curl -s http://localhost:1234/foo.txt
```

Running in another tab gets a lot trickier; this interleaves the output from the client and the server.

```
$ ./doit.sh
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2014 23:00:32] "GET /foo.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Fri 19 Sep 2014 23:00:32 MDT
```

Note the log output from the HTTP server, and the output from the HTTP client. The server is automatically killed afterwards.